# Low loss and very very low accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I'm training a deep learning model and get a very low accuracy , but also low loss , it's the two inversely related. what would be the cause of this very low accuracy and how can i stop it ?

The model should detect abnormal event in videos scenes

A link of the research paper i used to build the model

https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.04574

[image]

Model Architecture
[image]

Here's my code:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(512, 11, 11 ,activation='relu'  ,  border_mode='valid', subsample = (4,4))
                      , input_shape=(10,231, 231, 1)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, border_mode='valid')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(256,5, 5,activation='relu'  , border_mode='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, border_mode='valid')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(128,3,3,activation='relu'  , border_mode='same'))),
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2DTranspose(128, 3,3,border_mode='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2, ))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2DTranspose(256, 3,3,border_mode='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2, ))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2DTranspose(512,5,5,border_mode='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2DTranspose(1, kernel_size=(11,11),strides=(4,4))))
```

Comment: Maybe your model is wrong. Plz give more details.

Comment: I will post the code in the problem description.

Comment: you should describe you target. But from your code, I think it's obviously you misunderstand `TimeDistributed` layer.

Comment: The model should learn temporal features from frames , so i try to train it on 10 frames using **TimeDistributed** . the model is from research paper : **Learning Temporal Regularity in Video Sequences**. i will post a photo of model architecture in problem description.

Comment: Is this a regression or classification problem? What loss are you using? Ti me it seems you are using accuracy for regression, which is the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have deleted accuracy as a metric. The model try to present/learn frames, so when tested it detect abnormal frames. the loss used is mean absolute error (mae).

Answer (score 6):

The problem lies in a fact that the task you are solving here is more a regression task than a classification task. When `accuracy` is computed - an example is marked correctly if two `float` numbers are equal what is extremely rare even when you have a really good model. So I would not carry a lot about accuracy and try to compute e.g. `R2` score instead.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'am going to delete accuracy metrics from model.